# Is there an adjective that means "under development"? I need one for a document title

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

The title of a template document I'm translating is quite long and goes like this:

> Comparison of the formulations of the drug under development *Trade name (INN), dosage form, strength, manufacturer, country* and the reference drug product *Trade name (INN), dosage form, strength, manufacturer, country*.

In Russian it reads just fine, but I'm unsure about the "drug under development" bit in English. Isn't it clumsy? In Russian, the notion is expressed by a single adjective, разрабатываемый (razrabatyvayemyi = being currently developed). The drug is being developed by the company I'm translating the text for.

Is there a way of expressing it in an adjective or adjective phrase in English? The adjective **developed** would mean that the drug has already been developed, and this would be quite off the mark for my purpose.

I'm thinking of making the whole "drug under development" a parenthesis - for instance, by surrounding it with commas or round brackets.

> Comparison of the formulations of *Trade name (INN), dosage form, strength, manufacturer, country* (drug under development) and *Trade name (INN), dosage form, strength, manufacturer, country* (reference drug product).

The original title  in Russian:

> Сравнение составов **разрабатываемого** лекарственного препарата «Торговое наименование (МНН), лекарственная форма, дозировка», производитель, страна
>   и референтного лекарственного препарата «Торговое наименование (МНН), ЛФ, дозировка», производитель, страна

Comment: The parentheses don't work, as they make their contents incidental. You presumably want grouping of an important term.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a fitting adjective. Most likely you'll need a phrase and what you have ("the drug under development Trade name") reads ok.

If you are still unhappy, might I suggest changing it to one of these:

- "the drug currently/presently under development"
- "the drug currently/presently being developed"
- "the drug currently/presently in development"

since "currently" adds a little more emphasis on the idea of not being finished, but still in development. I hope that helps